# What does なんだろ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does なんだろ mean in the following sentence?

太陽が夜に、なんだろ、「日が沈む」といいます。

なんだろ itself means something like "I wonder", but how does it suits in that sentence?

Comment: Isn't this a straight-up translation request? What have you found out about なんだろ by yourself up to now? Do you have an idea what it could mean already?

Comment: @SevenOclock edited.

Comment: The sentence doesn't make much sense by itself, with or without the apparent insertion of なんだろ. Assuming it doesn't contain typos and other errors, context might help. If it's a quote from something you found online, please link it. If it's from your recollection of something you have heard, please explain the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how it's surrounded by commas. It's probably "what can I say?" or "how should I put this?" added as a [parenthetical aside/interjection](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/8-types-of-parenthetical-phrases/).